# Where are the preferences for HGEclipse plugin in Eclipse 3.5?

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, eclipse-plugin

I've installed HgEclipse plugin from the update site: http://hge.javaforge.com/hgeclipse

From some reason, when I go to Window->Preferences, I can't find the category Mercurial under Team.

Someone knows how to solve this?

My eclipse version is 3.5 (Galileo).
My plugin version is 1.5.0

I have hg 1.4 installed on my machine.
I'm running on Fedora Core 11.

Thanks!

Asaf

Comment: I have the exact same problem. HgEclipse is sparesely listed under Help->About->Installation->Installed, but nowhere else in eclipse.
I think it might have to do with the special fedora version of eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

It means the installation did not complete successfully.

Could you check your logs (Windows / Show Views / Error logs) to see what gone wrong?

Comment: Nothing in the log from the hgeclipse plugin

Answer (score 0):

The project URL is http://javaforge.com/project/HGE, when you create an account and put your issue into the prokect's bug tracker, you will get help there.

Comment: I'm in the Bug Tracker screen for the project but could not find any button to open a new bug/issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seams the problem is related to a (fedora?)eclipse bug, and issues with permissions to the plugin folder.

I solved it by uninstalling hgeclipse, starting eclipse as root, installing hgeclipse, and then restarting as my normal user again.